# Dynamic path routing in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I have 300 entries defined in `routes` file, like so:

```
GET /url001 MyClass.myMethod
```

This works with URLs such as `http://localhost:9000/url001`

Now, I need to define two environments for these 300 links, for production and testing. The links would be like:

```
http://localhost:9000/prod/url001
```

for production (see `prod` in the path)

and

```
http://localhost:9000/test/url001
```

for testing (see `test` in the path).

I want to have a single set of links in `routes`, how can this be achieved in Play? I know that I can define a variable in the path, such as `path/:var`, but what I need is to set a relative URL.

**Note:** Some users may be using `prod` while others may be using `test` *simultaneously*

Comment: You need to have both `/test` and `/prod` living at the same time or it is just a configuration issue between environments? If you just have a diferent path between test and prod environments, you can use `play.http.context` like adding `play.http.context="/test" in your `conf/application.conf`. See how to use different configuration files for each env here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file

Comment: They have to live at the same time, some users may be using `prod` while others may be using `test` simultaneously

Comment: Why not deploy to different environments one for test and one for prod.

Comment: Because the test environment will not be used to actually test the system. It's for a business intelligence application where the user will test the queries they build before migrating them to production. From the system perspective, both `prod` and `test` are production. From the user perspective, `prod` and `test` are different environments.

Comment: You could define it like this, right : ```GET /:environment/url001 MyClass.myMethod```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SIRD (String Interpolating Routing DSL): 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSirdRouter#Binding-sird-Router

You will need to describe that 30 entries in the scala source, then do the two records in routes and bind them to your scala custom router.

The custom router will looks like:

```
package my.app

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._

class MainRouter @Inject()(controller: ApiController)
  extends SimpleRouter
{
  override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/url001") => MyClass.myMethod001
    case GET(p"/url002") => MyClass.myMethod002
  }
}
```

The `conf/routes` will look like:

```
/prod                        my.app.MainRouter
/test                        my.app.MainRouter
```

Still, you need somehow to understand what is what inside the app, I do not know what is your idea - session (cookies) or tokens or...

> Because the test environment will not be used to actually test the system. It's for a business intelligence application where the user will test the queries they build before migrating them to production. From the system perspective, both prod and test are production. From the user perspective, prod and test are different environments

In this case, I will advise you to create two different installments.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having as set of repeated routes which would introduce a lot of copy/paste code, maybe it's better to have a role based logic. 
Assuming that there is some kind of session management/user identification mechanism set in place, then the test users can have test credentials, that when logged in will have a role/session attribute to indicate the test only capabilities. 
Ideally you would have different dedicated instances, since it already looks like they are used for different things.